# iPadOS 14 keyboard-like Bluetooth device button remapping

Tags: ipad, keyboard, bluetooth, accessibility, ipados

I'm annoyed I can’t remap keys on a Mocuto 052 “VR remote"-like device on my iPadOS 14.

[image: Mocuto 052]

I intended to use it with Procreate to have a physical access to undo-redo shortcuts and others.

I expected gamepad detection and full ablity to map the buttons using native system settings.

- Ideally I want to remap existing shortcuts inside Procreate
- I've tried a load of different firmwares for the controller (iPadOS always detects a keyboard, regardless of side switch position
- I'm willing to jailbreak my device, if it helps.

So what I'm asking is: is there a way to remap the buttons I'm getting from my Bluetooth keyboard-like device?